# Google Analytics style number incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I'm making an add-on for a fundraising site where it automatically updates the amount raised without having to refresh. I'm able to get the new amount without a problem, but instead of fading in/out when updated, I wanted to make it count up to the new number like Google Analytics does on the real time stats page.

I've tried using a for loop to increment up but I think the problem is adding a delay. any ideas?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823005/jquery-count-up-animation

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need:  live data, and a way to show it.

For the data, you can either poll your server on a regular basis, or use something such as websockets (or one of the many ways of emulating that behavior).  What you choose depends on  your needs, and what is available server-side.  I personally would use Node.JS with Socket.IO.  It's very compatible, and can provide you with near-real-time updates.

Now for displaying it, you can do something simple such as ["animating" a number in a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13501577/362536).  There are also [handy gauges and what not in the Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge).